# graphicx,\rotatebox Having the origin of rotation end up in the same place within the surrounding box where it would end up if the box wasn't rotated

Tags: graphics, rotating

For illustrating things I created a mwe where within a table you have cells where a box containing Some text is rotated around its reference point.

The left and right column contain the same. The right column additionally contains some rectangles so that you can see the reference points of the original boxes and measurements of boxes resulting from rotation.

When looking at the second row, then it seems the command `\rotatebox` of the package graphicx wraps the result of rotation into a box.

**When placing into the surrounding box the box that is delivered by the `\rotatebox`-command, I would like the rotated origin of rotation end up in the same place where it would end up if the box was not rotated. As can be seen in the third table row of the result of compiling the example below. (With the mwe below, "the surrounding box" is the box holding the content of the table-cell created by the tabular environment.)**

As I chose the special case where rotation is done around the reference point of the box at an angle of 45 degrees counterclockwise, some "manual" shifting/kerning to the left was needed which could be calculated easily.

**But I still wonder if I overlooked a less cumbersome way that might be described in grfguide for having the rotated origin of rotation end up in the same place within the surrounding box where it would end up if the box was not rotated. (With the mwe below, "the surrounding box" is the box holding the content of the table-cell created by the tabular environment.)**

(For calculating things one could place things as rotated and unrotated `\phantom`s wrapped into boxes of zero width/height/depth holding tikzpictures for storing some coordinates..., but I wonder if there is some easy way of doing things which I overlooked when reading grfguide.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n\ExplSyntaxOff

\newbox\boxtorotate

\newlength\scratchy
\newcommand\Osepfbox[1]{{%
  \scratchy=\fboxsep
  \colorlet{saved}{.}%
  \fboxsep=-\fboxrule
  \color{lightgray}%
  \fbox{\fboxsep=\scratchy\color{saved}#1}%
}}%

\newcommand*\referencepointbox{%
  \hbox{%
    {%
      \color{lightgray}%
      \kern-\fboxrule \kern-\fboxsep \kern-.2pt
      \vbox{%
        \hbox{%
          \fbox{\vrule height 0.2pt depth 0.2pt width 0.4pt}%
        }%
        \kern-\prevdepth
      }%
      \kern-\fboxrule \kern-\fboxsep \kern-0.2pt
    }%
    \copy\boxtorotate
  }%
}%

\newcommand*\noreferencepointbox{\hbox{\copy\boxtorotate}}

\begin{document}

\setbox\boxtorotate=\hbox{Some text}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline&\\
\rlap{\noreferencepointbox}\rotatebox[x=0pt, y=0pt]{0}{\noreferencepointbox}&
\rlap{\referencepointbox}\Osepfbox{\rotatebox[x=0pt, y=0pt]{0}{\referencepointbox}}%
\\&\\
\hline&\\
\rlap{\noreferencepointbox}\rotatebox[x=0pt, y=0pt]{45}{\noreferencepointbox}&
\rlap{\referencepointbox}\Osepfbox{\rotatebox[x=0pt, y=0pt]{45}{\referencepointbox}}%
\\&\\
\hline&\\
\rlap{\noreferencepointbox}%
\kern-\fpeval{sqrt((\ht\boxtorotate)*(\ht\boxtorotate)*0.5)}pt 
\rotatebox[x=0pt, y=0pt]{45}{\noreferencepointbox}&
\rlap{\referencepointbox}%
\kern-\fpeval{sqrt((\ht\boxtorotate)*(\ht\boxtorotate)*0.5)}pt
\Osepfbox{\rotatebox[x=0pt, y=0pt]{45}{\referencepointbox}}%
\\&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With tikz? \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=south west]{Some text};
    \node[anchor=south west,rotate=45]{Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: you can make the thing you are rotating have zero size (\smash\rlap, or picture(0,0) or tikz, ...  then the origin will not move